# Proper output, website is utf-8, mysql is latin1_swedish_ci

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, mariadb, iso-8859-1

I'm writing a webinterface for an existing database that I can't really make changes to.
The database uses collation latin1_swedish_ci.
For the page I'm using UTF-8 as the charset.

When connecting to the database in PHP I use set_charset("utf8") and in the HTML head I define content="text/html; charset=UTF-8".

With this everything mostly works but there are some cases where symbols don't come out as expected. Notable are ü which comes out as just a square in the browser () and £ which comes out as œ.

I tried not setting a charset when connecting and defining Win-1252, ISO-8859-1, or nothing in the HTML but that just ends up with more missing characters and sometimes evening queries failing...

Any ideas on how to deal with some of these struggling symbols?

Comment: You can't store UTF8 in a latin1 table as UTF8. You could convert the UTF8 chars to entities if you really can't upgrade to UTF8. e.g. instead of `ü` store `&uuml;`

Comment: In addition to user3783243's comment, MySQL's UTF8 isn't really UTF8 as it only supports the first three bytes so if you can make schema changes, use UTF8MB4 instead.

Comment: Also in addition to user3783243: warning that if you escape or add entities, any search or other use of the data may break (e.g. double escaping & because it is user input, etc.). I really recommend that you convince to update the database. Now web is UTF-8 (not just default, it is really in the standard: only utf-8 is allowed). To convince: emoji cannot be stored in Latin1. [But use UTF8MB4 for emoji]. Look online on how to change encoding of a field (without need to create again the database, or using temporary tables/fields, or shutting down the database)]

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing charset cp850 with latin1.  Hex 9C is the POUND SIGN in cp850 and
LATIN SMALL LIGATURE OE in latin1 or cp1256 (not 1252)

```
                                    cp850   2  1 '£'
                           cp1256, latin1   2  1 'œ'
```

Be sure to connect to the database with the charset that the client is using.  Then be consistent.